# How to select more than 1 value in SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run the query below and I get an error that reads:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

```
DECLARE @SchoolType VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1);
DECLARE @School int;
DECLARE @Counter int = 0;
SET @delimiter=','
SET @SchoolType =(SELECT  School_Type FROM crm_portal_announcements_messages where id > 0 group by id, School_Type)
SET @School=(SELECT  Item FROM SplitString(@SchoolType, @delimiter) group by item )
 
while (@Counter<= 4)
begin
print @School
PRINT 'The counter value is = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@School)
SET @Counter  += 1
--set @counter=@counter+1
end
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; what about the error  don't you understand and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  The error seems really clear as do the problems with the subqueries.  Perhaps you should also describe what you are trying to do, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am not understanding how to make it return multiple values

Comment: *"I am not understanding how to make it return multiple values"* Why do you want to? `@SchoolType` is a **scalar** variable; it can't contain multiple values. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here? The fact that you are trying to assign multiple values to a scalar variable, and have a `WHILE` suggests several design flaws.

Comment: As noted in other comments, the error message tells you the problem:  return multiple values is "not permitted".  There is no workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you stored more values into a single variable, in that case I suggest you to store all the results into a temp table with an identity column, then use the where ID = @count to get a single result. for example

```
create #Temp(id int identity, SchoolType varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT  School_Type FROM crm_portal_announcements_messages where id > 0 group by id, School_Type

DECLARE @DELIMITER varchar(1)
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @School VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @SchoolType VARCHAR(20)

WHILE @COUNT <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp) 
BEGIN
    select @SchoolType = SchoolType FROM #temp WHERE id = @Count
    SELECT @School = Item FROM SplitString(@SchoolType, @delimiter) group by item
    
    print @School
    PRINT 'The counter value is = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@School)

SET @Count = @Count + 1

END
```